# fecth api not posting data to nodeserver

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, post, fetch-api

i have a node backend set up, when i send a get request, it works perfectly, but when i send a post request it doesn't send the data to the backend.
Here is my code:

```
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/", { method: "POST",body:{"title":title.value,"content":content.value}})
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
```

i have even tried sending it through the formdata object it is still not working:

```
  const formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("title",title.value)
    formdata.append("content",content.value)


    fetch("http://localhost:3000/", { method: "POST",body:formdata})
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
```

this is the console.log:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sCdh.png)

this is the backend:

```
//crud applications
app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { title, content } = req.body;

  try {
    const newPost = await postModel.create({ title, content });
    res.json(newPost);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Is your backend logging the receipt of the data, or sending anything back? You didn't add that code to your question.

Comment: @Andy yes it is sending back the id and some information that is supposed to be in the database, but it is not posting the data i sent through fetch api

Comment: Why do you expect the problem in the frontend and not in the backend? Do you get a CORS error in your browser console?

Comment: @jabaa no i have fixed the cors error

Comment: Do you see a POST request and a response in the network monitor? Isn't the output in your console the result of the POST request?

Comment: @jabaa that is the response, but the title and content(the data i am sending) is supposed to be part of the JSON object that is being returned

Comment: Again: Why do you expect the problem in the frontend? Does the request in the network monitor contain the data? Does the response in the network monitor contain the data?

Comment: @jabaa when i use postman it works correctly, but i have edited the post and added the backend to it

Comment: Does the request in the network monitor contain the data? Does the response in the network monitor contain the data? Have you tried to start the backend with your debugger? Set a breakpoint at `const { title, content } = req.body;`. What are the values of `title` and `content`? Set a breakpoint at `res.json(newPost);`. What's the value of `newPost`?

Comment: @jabaa i don't have access to the node code on my debugger only the html and js that i wrote

Comment: Why do you avoid answering my questions regarding the network monitor? You have the code. Why can't you debug it? Obviously you have access to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using fetch, use Axios. import it in your HTML with this CDN `<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>`

and then use this code it should work:

```
  const data = {
      title: title.value,
      content: content.value,
    };
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/", data).then((response) => {
      const result = response.data;
      console.log(result);
     
    });
```